# hashmap keySet() method returns only first element

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I'm trying to loop over a HashMap called products by the following code :

```
public Product findProduct (int id)
{
    Product result = null;
    for (Product product : products.keySet())
    {
        if (product.getId() == id)
            result = product;
        break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

the thing is at runtime , products contains 2 elements

[image]

but the product:products.keySet() returns only the first element and I don't know why, resulting that if I passed 102 to the method, it will throw an exception.

Comment: I think the most important piece of advice here is to format your code correctly. The indentation does not match structure. (I also always use braces after a bad experience early in my career.)

Comment: Voting to close as typo. Your if-statement is really this: `if(product.getId()==id) { result=product; } break;` i.e. always break after the first element

Comment: This is no way to use a map. You should have another `HashMap<ID, Product>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saying that `products.keySet()` is returning only one element based on the iterations that your loop is going through?

I can see that you've put a `break;` statement after the `result=product;` statement which is causing your loop to exit on the first iteration itself. If this wasn't intentional, this might be the culprit here.

You can try to put the statements after `if` in a block like this

```
if(product.getId()==id){
   result=product;
   break;      
}
```